# NT Eventlog single message size

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, event-log

Can anybody tell me what is maximum size of a windows NT log message? I know that it is possible to reset the maximum log size of event log from 32 MB. I am interested about the memory a single message can hold in NT event log.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is 32766 characters ~ 32 KB

See a example below:
Error: Log entry string is too long. A string written to the event log cannot exceed 32766 characters.

Comment: 32766 characters is stated to be true for Windows OS before Vista.
The actual limit varies by OS. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/aa363679.aspx `lpStrings`. For Vista or newer it's 31389 characters. Although I found limit of 31914 on Windows 7 to be working.

Comment: @thepip3r I realize I am late to the game, but I believe the other answer was posted almost 11 months *later*, not before.

Answer (score 13):

In Windows Server 2008 the maximum size of a single Event Log entry is: 31,839 characters
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/aa363679.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Starting from windows Vista the maximum size in bytes was reduced from 32,766 to 31,839 byes.

So lets say you want to know a C# string maximum allowed length, you'll have to run:

`int EventViewerMaximumMessageLength = 31839 / sizeof(Char);`

And you'r string will have to be trimmed accordingly:

```
string trimmedEventLogMessage = message.Length > EventViewerMaximumMessageLength
                ? message.Substring(0, EventViewerMaximumMessageLength)
                : message;
```