# Log4net set EventLogAppender size

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

Is there any way to specify the size of the event viewer log using EventLogAppender?

Or do I need to grab the logger using the C#/Windows Api's?

By default it's set to 1028KB but I need it to be 10MB.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to be 10 MB? The event log [can only hold entries of ~32 KB anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418312/nt-eventlog-single-message-size).

Comment: It's not the individual message that I want to be 10MB,. it's the all log.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748849.aspx

Comment: I need it to be done programmatically, preferably using Log4Net EventLogAppender properties. Currently I'm making it by using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.maximumkilobytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using this:

```
public static void setEventLogAppenderMaximumSize(log4net.ILog aLogger)
{
    log4net.Appender.IAppender[] logAppenders = aLogger.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders();
    if (logAppenders != null && logAppenders.Length > 0)
    {
        string logName = ((log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender)logAppenders[0]).LogName;

        EventLog[] eventLogs = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
        foreach (EventLog e in eventLogs)
        {
            if (e.Log == logName)
            {
                int newLogSizeInKB = 102400;    //10MB

                if (e.MaximumKilobytes < newLogSizeInKB)
                {
                    e.MaximumKilobytes = newLogSizeInKB;
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words, the answer is no. You can't set the log size using log4net alone.